# "Deployed null" when mvn embedded-glassfish:run is executed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, glassfish

Here's my long story. I've been assigned to a new project in my workplace requires creation and use of RESTful webservices. We are using maven and it's embedded glassfish server along with Eclipse to create the application. I'm completely new to it and I'm trying hard to understand it.

1. I managed to create a Dynamic web application using maven (through command line) as explained here:     http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/giqdq/
2. There were multiple errors while executing mvn embedded-glassfish:run command. So, did an extensive read through the articles available and modified my POM.xml.
3. Now, there are no errors and when I execute mvn embedded-glassfish:run, this is the message I get.

   ```
   Mar 24, 2014 9:56:59 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService creat
   eNetworkProxy
   INFO: Network listener https-listener on port 0 disabled per domain.xml
   Mar 24, 2014 9:56:59 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy$2$1 onR
   eady
   INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 65ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
   Mar 24, 2014 9:56:59 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup run
   INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (java_re-private) startup time
   : Embedded (510ms), startup services(491ms), total(1,001ms)
   Mar 24, 2014 9:56:59 AM org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXCon
   nectorsStarterThread run
   INFO: JMX006: JMXStartupService had disabled JMXConnector system
   Mar 24, 2014 9:56:59 AM PluginUtil startGlassFish
   INFO: Started GlassFish ServerId = maven, GlassFish = com.sun.enterprise.glassfi
   sh.bootstrap.StaticGlassFishRuntime$1@1fe55fd, TimeTaken = 678 ms
   Mar 24, 2014 9:56:59 AM PluginUtil doDeploy
   INFO: Deployed null
   Hit ENTER to redeploy, X to exit
   ```

NOTE: When I press X and exits, I get a message like this:

```
    Mar 24, 2014 12:01:43 PM PluginUtil doUndeploy
    INFO: Deployer = com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl@1a3af98
    PlainTextActionReporterFAILUREApplication RestHelloApp is not deployed on this
    arget [server]Mar 24, 2014 12:01:43 PM PluginUtil doUndeploy
    INFO: Undeployed RestHelloApp
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 02:46 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2014-03-24T12:01:43+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/37M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1. When I try to test the application in the browser,  I'm getting http error 404.

Could you please help me out:

1. How to know whether the server is really running ?
2. What am I missing here?

Here's my POM.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-  v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.xerox</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestHelloApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestHelloApp</name>
    <build>
    <finalName>RestHelloApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>  
            <configuration>    
            <user>admin</user>
            <adminPassword>admin</adminPassword>
            <goalPrefix>glassfish</goalPrefix>
            <app>target/RestHelloApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</app>
            <port>8080</port>
            <contextRoot>RestHelloApp</contextRoot>
            <name>RestHelloApp</name>
            <glassfishDirectory>C:\glassfish3</glassfishDirectory>

            </configuration>  
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                         <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>    
        </plugin>       
    </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
          <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
          <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.29</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.json</groupId>
          <artifactId>json</artifactId>
          <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
          <version>20041127.091804</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-alpha-2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.distributions</groupId>
        <artifactId>web-all</artifactId>
        <version>10.0-build-20080430</version>
        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
        <artifactId>gf-embedded-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>


    </dependency>


    </dependencies>



    <properties>
      <jersey-version>1.8</jersey-version>
    </properties>


    <repositories>


    <repository>
        <id>glassfish.java.net</id>
        <name>GlassFish Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/embedded/maven-embedded-  glassfish-plugin/3.1.2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>m2.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/embedded/maven-embedded- glassfish-plugin/3.1.2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>        
    </repositories>



    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/</url>

    </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>  
    </project>
```

Comment: Did you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250095/deployed-null-when-using-embedded-glassfish-server

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But when I changed the goal prefix to embedded-glassfish and the group id to org.glassfish, I'm getting errors in mvn embedded-glassfish:run telling that "No Plugin found for the prefix "embedded-glassfish in the current project and in the plugin groups".But thanks for your help.